# HP Printer Error - "Unsupported Personality: PCL"

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

Ubuntu 16.04 
Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5607 @ 2.27GHz × 8 
64-bit

HP Laser Jet 1012 using hp-Laser-jet-1012 driver

Each time I print I get an extra page printed at the end of my print job with the error "This error condition occurs by design when an attempt to print with a PCL5e or PCL6 printer driver occurs and is NOT a bug within the product software.  Install the correct HP LaserJet Host-Based Printer Driver or the HP LaserJet printing system software for the product."
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00063454

My desktop has the correct driver. Therefore after sudo apt-get update - sudo apt-get upgrade I went to 
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html
I download the latest version of HPLIP to get access to new features and bug fixes, as suggested.

I still have the same error. I am lost. Does only have an idea what is the cause of this error -- "Unsupported Personality: PCL"

Comment: What applications are you printing with? Does it happen with all applications?

Comment: Sorry didn't think of this. I use Firefox 49.0, Chrome 54.0.2840.59, Thunderbird 45.3.0 and LibreOffice 5.1.4.2.  Yes, it happens with every one. Yes it does happen with every print job from every application I print from.

Answer (score 1):

Update from https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_1010 (some time in the last several years):

> The problem of the "Unsupported Personality: PCL" was finally solved
> by Carl Michal (michal at physics dot ubc dot ca). By analyzing the
> output of the Windows driver he found out that after the BeginSession
> operator in the beginning of a PCL 6 job a special sequence of 8 bytes
> has to be added. He added it by a filter to the output of
> Ghostscript's "pxlmono" driver and from then on the printer worked
> (Implemented as the "pxl1010" driver on this site).

That "pxl1010" driver is https://www.openprinting.org/driver/pxl1010, but it says its deprecated, and hplip (https://www.openprinting.org/driver/hplip/) is the recommended replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem printing to an old (c.2003) HP LaserJet 1010 from Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS running on a Dell Inspiron 15. HPLIP 3.18.12 finds the printer and installs it but when printing only blank pages come out.

To get it working I deleted the printer from HPLIP and installed it through the CUPS web interface http://localhost:631 and chose the HP LaserJet 1010 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11 under Make & Model options, not the HP LaserJet 1010, hpcups 3.18.12 (en) option/s.

This does work but occasionally one gets a long delay on a print job and a blank page with "Unsupported Personality: PCL" printed at the top. As described below, the only solution to this seems to be to turn the printer off and on again, and retry the print job.

(http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_1010
"Unfortunately, the new LaserJet 1010/1012 series seems not to be absolutely compatible with older HP printers or it has a firmware bug. Sometimes it happens that the printer stops working and reports the error "Unsupported Personality: PCL". It only continues working when one kills the job and power-cycles the printer.")